# Rich Calendar Validator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm new to JSF and I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I've been trying different things for days and cant make any progress.  I'm trying to do validation when a user types in a date instead of using the rich calendar but for some reason I cant seem to get the validator to fire.  The page code is as follows:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="responseReleaseDate" rendered="#{appealSearchManager.isVendor}">
    <p><h:outputText value="#{messages.ResponseReleaseDate}"/></p>
    <rich:calendar id="responseReleaseDateBegin" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
        enableManualInput="true"
        buttonIcon="/images/calendar_icon.jpg" buttonClass="calendar"
        validator="#{appealSearchManager.validateResponseReleaseDateBegin}"
        value="#{appealSearchManager.responseReleaseDateBegin}">
    </rich:calendar>
    <rich:calendar id="responseReleaseDateEnd" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
        enableManualInput="true"
        buttonIcon="/images/calendar_icon.jpg" buttonClass="calendar"
        validator="#{appealSearchManager.validateResponseReleaseDateBegin}"
    value="#{appealSearchManager.responseReleaseDateEnd}">
    </rich:calendar>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The bean code I'm trying to invoke is as follows:

```
    public void validateResponseReleaseDateBegin(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
        try {
            simpleDateFormat.parse(value.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                MessageFormat.format((RootUtils.getCommonBundle().getString(BundleConstants.INVALID_ITEM)), "Response Release Date"),
                MessageFormat.format(RootUtils.getCommonBundle().getString(BundleConstants.INVALID_DATE_FORMAT), "Date", "MM/DD/YYYY")));

        }
    }
}
```

The wierd thing is that I can reach the validateResponseReleaseDateBegin(...) method using the code below (I know, it doesnt make sense for a text field, it was just for testing purposes). But I never hit the method when I enter input for the rich calendar.

```
<div class="div30">
    <p><h:outputText value="#{messages.ProgramInvoiceId}"/></p>
    <h:inputText id="programInvoiceId"
        validator="#{appealSearchManager.validateResponseReleaseDateBegin}"
        value="#{appealSearchManager.programInvoiceId}"/>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this validator works in one place and not another?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need a validator for the format if the `<rich:calendar>` is already "validating" it by itself during the implicit conversion step from `String` to `Date`?

Comment: The requirements state that I need to gather all the validation data and put it into a pop-up (using JQuery) and I was having difficulty getting the Faces messages to appear for the date fields.  With the other fields this approach above worked.  Maybe I should go back and figure out why these Faces Messages wont show up first and then use the internal validator.

Comment: I think you didn't understood the real problem. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes no sense. The `<rich:calendar>` will already implicitly convert the `String` submitted value to `Date` before setting it as model value. If you enter a date in invalid format, the `<rich:calendar>` will already throw a `ConverterException` for that. Its message should already be visible in any `<h:messages>` or `<h:message>` component associated with the component.

As conversion runs *before* validation, your validator is never fired when conversion fails. Even when your validator was fired, the `Object value` argument in the validator is **already** of the type `java.util.Date`. So if your validator was fired, it would *always* have thrown an exception because [`Date#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) does definitely not match `MM/dd/yyyy`.

I'm not sure why you need this validator. Perhaps you just wanted to supply a custom conversion error message? In that case, you should be using its `converterMessage` attribute instead.

```
<rich:calendar ... converterMessage="Invalid date" />
```

Or, if you really need to "validate" the date format by yourself, implement a custom `Converter` instead and register it by `converter` attribute or `<f:converter>` tag instead.

Comment: Thanks!  The converterMessage is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future questions, don't forget to state the functional requirement more clearly. You should try to ask how to solve a problem, not how to achieve a solution of which you *thought* that it is the right solution for the problem :)